# is it possible to use dynamic cast in an interface like architecture in c++

Tags: c++, architecture, software-design

I m kinda new in c++ and I had this problem:

Is it possible to access the *parent pointer in class Object with having a:

```
class Object      (*parent ptr here pointing to the parent or nullPtr if it is  root)
class IStorage   <- which contains the ability of an object to nest children
class ISearch    <- which contains the ability to search in a given container
class Container : public virtual Object,public virtual IStorage,public virtual Isearch   <-  resulting class
```

Now in Istorage I have a method `virtual void addChild(T* obj)` which when adding a child should update the *parent of the child but I dont know if I can access it.

Is it possible to get the pointer to the Object from the IStorage
Is this architecture bad? Should I just opt for a generic Tree like architecture?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If possible I'd get rid of that `parent` pointer.

Comment: It's an understandable misconception that you think you need to create a "searchable, storable, polymorphic container that can hold anything". But you don't. Deriving every class from some base "Object" type is very poor practice (yes, I know that MFC and QT do it - people were less experienced in those days). Containment is one concern, searching is another, storing is yet another. Treat them separately.

Comment: @DanielJour I m going for a tree structure and from what I researched simple pointers to parents and smart boost::ptr_vector to children seemed most logical

Comment: @T.Zak yes, but why do you need access to the parent from the child? Do you have a specific use case in mind?

Comment: @DanielJour it is intended for a cad like project where ownership is defined as   "house owns room ,   room owns table , table owns jar , etc",so there must be an ownership attribute in case objects change location,thus parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid There is no hack-free way, what you could do is to add to IStorage a `virtual Object* getObject() = 0;` and define it inside Container as such : `Object* getObject() override { return this; }`.

Another way (more OOP friendly in my opitnion) would be to add to IStorage a virtual method like : `virtual void updateAfterAddChild() = 0;` and implement it inside Container, which would call appropriate method on `Object` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I went with this one (the updateAfterChild) and worked really smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If IStorage knows about its contents' structure, the parent pointer should be located there, so it will be accessible.

Otherwise, maybe you should derive Object from IStorage and override addChild there.